# Check hierarchical Custom Settings instance existing in Apex Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've created tab and trying to pass all Custom Setting fields as a query parameters. For this purposes I use $Setup global merge field. My url

```
https://mysite.com/page?q1={!$Setup.prefix__Settings__c.prefix__TextField1__c}&q2={!$Setup.prefix__Settings__c.prefix__BoolField2__c}
```

But I have one problem when there is no custom settings instance created. prefix__TextField1__c is text, and it's passed as and empty string (this value is allowed for me), but prefix__BoolField2__c passed as false, but I expect default value true.

Is it possible to chect that $Setup.prefix__Settings__c returns any instance and then use prefix__BoolField2__c  value or specific value?

I have tried to use `NULLVALUE($Setup.prefix__Settings__c)` and `IF(ISBLANK($Setup.prefix__Settings__c))` but `$Setup.prefix__Settings__c` returns core.apexpages.el.DynamicGlobalReferenceELAdapter string instead of NULL or any other object.

I understand that I can add one more field (original field allow, and pair - disallow) to custom settings (that would be negative for original field) and change query params handling in my service. But I would like to avoid this way because two fields for single entity will be confusing

Comment: Did you create an org default setting? You should always set one up as a fallback.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, do you mean that it's possible to populate org-wide settings  into the package? In current package we don't populate org-wide custom settings, but call that global variables, so SF pass default values, but these default values doesn't match to custom setting fields defaults. I think it's SF type fields defaults: false for bool, empty for string and numbers etc

Comment: You should be able to populate the values in a post-install script, I would think...